# Null reference exception was unhandled in c#

Tags: c#, function

For example in section a: i have a random number and  in the section b: i want to multiply that random number by 2 but it has to be in a function and then section c: has to add 10 and so on. I guess this is very simple for you guys. and i am sure i am writing very silly codes but i am not a programmer.

thanks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Boot boot = new Boot();
        Game game = new Game();

        Console.WriteLine("Matrix Lengte: " + game.Matrix);
        Console.WriteLine("Lengte boot: " + boot.Lengte);

        Console.ReadLine();

class Game
{
    private Boot boot;
    private int matrix;

    public int Matrix
    {
        get { return matrix; }
        set { matrix = value; }
    }

    public Game()
    {    
        matrix= boot.Lengte*2;
    }

    internal Boot Boot
    {
        get { return boot; }
        set { boot = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default fields have their default values, which is `null` for reference types. So, just add `boot` initialization:

```
public Game()
{
    boot = new Boot(); // or pass via constructor parameter
    matrix = boot.Lengte * 2;
}
```

Comment: thank you.its works. Can you also tell me why we have to write boot= new Boot();

Comment: @user3081200 that's what I wrote in first place. `boot` is a field of your class. If you are not assigning value directly to this field, then it will have default value when class instance is created

Comment: +1 For quick, correct answer. On a side note, amazes me how incredibly stupid some people are; Mr. Copy/Paste guy.

Comment: Because you have to create an instance of the class `Boot` in your `Game` class. Doing so in your main method is not the correct way as `boot` is a field inside the class.